# How to create a python script (Django) that triggers itself at a specific time?

Tags: python, django

I devellope a web application which must recover the data on another site every day at 00: 00h.
To trigger the recovery of the data I had to create a middleware which is based on a request sent by any user who would navigate on the site around 00: 00h.
Until then everything works normally.

Problem: Retrieving data takes a long time and this disrupts the navigation of the user in question.

Question: So I wanted to know how to do without this mechanism by creating a script that is triggered by itself at 00: 00h without going through a request from any of the user.

Thanks to everyone who will help me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can easily check for the current time and them wait until the desired time is reached using Timedelta, for example https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta. Or you can use the OS scheduler to run your script at the desired time, which for me would be the cleaner solution.

Comment: Check out Celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html